# How can I check "find" command (Linux) for search results in one-line script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

I have a task to write one-line script for searching files script.txt in the directory DOC, inside which there are lists of file names (in one column).

In these lists I need to find all lines that end with .sql
As a result, I need to find all previously found names with the ending .sql in the current directory and all subdirectories(recursive searching), writing all paths these files in the file sql_scripts.txt.

[image: file structure screen]

Output of file script.txt:

```
sergey@sergey dir5 % cat script.txt 
file1.sql
file.txt
fie2.sql
```

In this file line file1.sql should match ./file1.sql, file.txt shouldn't match, fie2.sql should match ./dir1/fie2.sql

The difficulty is that it is necessary to return non-zero exit code if at least one file could not be found.
Wrote the script:

```
find DOC/ -name script.txt -exec cat {} \; | awk '/^[^-].*\.sql$/{print}' | xargs -I sql_file find . -name sql_file -type f | tee sql_scripts.txt
```

I have no idea how to implement non-zero exit code in case the file is not found in this one-line script.
"Linux find", even if it doesn't find a specific file, will continue to search further and return exit-code 0.

I've seen similar questions, but most of them were like multi-line scripts. I need a one-line solution

Comment: Why do you need to use `find`? Why not just `grep '\.sql$' DOC/script.txt | ...`?

Comment: The exit status of `find` is not dependent on whether it finds any matches. It returns a non-zero status if it gets an error, e.g. the starting directory doesn't exist or it runs into permission problems.

Comment: If you want to know if it found anything, save the output somewhere (a file or variable) and check if it's non-empty.

Comment: _"a task to write one-line script"_ - I don't like the take on that. Why not be open for a _good_ script? One-line or not shouldn't matter.

Comment: Take the multiline scripts, fold them up into one line, and include `;` chars as needed.  It might help to share who is giving you this task and why they think it is important. Is this a job interview question? (One-liners are ***really*** a false prophet of coding.) /-;!  Good luck!

Comment: please define "could not be found".  `mkdir d; touch d/f.sql; chmod 0 d`. Can `d/f.sql` "be found"?

Comment: Stack Overflow is specifically focused on "practical, answerable" questions. Prioritizing terseness (one line) over readability, portability, robustness, maintainability, etc is inherently impractical.

Comment: if `DOC/dir1/script.txt` contains `flie1.sql` and there is a file `dir2/file1.sql`, is that match? What if there are both `dir2/file1.sql` and `dir4/dir7/file1.sql` ?

Comment: @jhnc I guess duplicating files is impossible

Comment: @jhnc Sorry, yes is a typo. `./file1.sql` match `file1.sql`

Answer (score 3):

**version 2**

Since you state you are using bash, process redirection is available:

```
awk -F/ '
  NR==FNR { if (/\.sql$/) a[$NF]; next }
  $NF in a { print; delete a[$NF] }
  END { exit length(a)!=0 }
' \
  <( find DOC/ -name script.txt -exec cat {} + ) \
  <( find . -name '*.sql' ) \
  >sql_scripts.txt
```

- cat content of all script.txt files into awk

  - store distinct sql filenames (without path) as keys of array `a`
- pass list of actual sql files (with path) to awk

  - if basename is in `a`, print, then delete from `a`
- at the end, if `a` is not empty, exit non-zero

Assumes list of basenames will fit comfortably in memory.

If `a.sql` is listed in a `script.txt` and both `dir1/a.sql` and `dir2/a.sql` exist, only one will be printed.

---

**version 1**

You can test for errors from whatever command you use to determine if any file is "not found".

For example, using `ls` [error messages](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html#tag_20_73_05):

```
find DOC/ -name script.txt -exec grep '\.sql$' {} \; |
tee sql_scripts.txt |
test -z "$( xargs ls 2>&1 >/dev/null )"
```

If you're worried that `xargs` output could become too large:

```
find DOC/ -name script.txt -exec grep '\.sql$' {} \; |
tee sql_scripts.txt |
test 0 = $(xargs ls 2>&1 >/dev/null | wc -l)
```

Or you could loop over the list and check for any `test -e` failures:

```
find DOC/ -name script.txt -exec grep '\.sql$' {} \; |
tee sql_scripts.txt |
while read -r f; do [[ -e $f ]] || echo 1; done |
exit $(tail -l)
```

Or combine test and writing output with Perl:

```
find DOC/ -name script.txt -exec grep '\.sql$' {} \; |
perl -ple '$e|=!-e; END{exit$e}' >sql_scripts.txt
```

Comment: [Don't use `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @tripleee you'll note I referenced posix - all I'm checking is that `ls` printed an error - which posix guarantees when a file is "not found"

Comment: @jhnc Thanks for answers.
I wanted to make one point. My second finding is to write the paths to the .sql files into sql_script.txt so I can execute them on another job (gitlab ci pipeline). And I need the job to fail if some file could not be found in the current directory.

Comment: @langepass88 all the versions of my code exit with non-zero if any file is not found

Comment: @jhnc And one more note about "ls". Files can be located in subfolders :)

Comment: @langepass88 my code looks in the current directory for the filename stored in script.txt as stated in your question. If that's not what you want you should provide more complete details

Comment: @jhnc. I've corrected my question. 
"As a result, I need to find all previously found names with the ending .sql in the current directory and all subdirectories(recursive searching), writing all paths these files in the file sql_scripts.txt."

Comment: @langepass88 also add examples of filesystem layout and file contents, explaining what should match and what shouldn't match

Comment: @ jhnc OMG, it's very hard for reading solution. Ok, can you suggest, how I can check files and return a non-zero exit code in an one-script solution in this case:
`xargs -a file_list.txt -I file_name find . -name file_name -type f > file_paths.txt`
I think it would be better to split the script into at least two lines :)

Comment: @langepass88 does something prevent you writing a multi-line, easy to read, script and simply running `bash /path/to/script` as your "one-line"?

Comment: Note that my awk code only runs the `find` search once; your `xargs`+`find` runs a separate `find` for every item in the list. For small list, this is okay, for large lists, it might slow things down noticably.

Comment: @jhnc team-lead)